# Codeigniter + Datatable custom edit / delete record

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

EDIT :

I want to create a custom edit / delete function for records I have in a datatable.

In datatable code I have :

```
$('#users tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
     // get the row id here and send it to button 

} );
```

When a user selects a row I want to get the row ID and send it to a button :

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('main/delete/$id')?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModel" role="button" class="btn-u btn-block">Delete</a>
```

$id (from the button link )  = ID of row selected by user.

Comment: This is a confusing question - It sounds like you want to add the id (of what?) to the hyperlink as a parameter - Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Adding the id will allow me to call a function in a controller and from there to do the rest.

Comment: do you have the html view of your table? I have encountered same as this (custom edit and delete button).. And I have figured out a solution. But I am confused with your question..

Comment: I have change the description on the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For delete the answer can be found here :

[Codeigniter + dataTable custom delete with bootstrap model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139201/codeigniter-datatable-custom-delete-with-bootstrap-model/29139367?noredirect=1#comment46503005_29139367)

and for edit just add one more link in model.