# Ignited-Datatables, how should be done?

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Well to be honest, I´m clueless on how it´s going with the code, I´ve been doing this stuff, ´been reading this and that, and came with no result. I´m still a newbie in programing. The main problem is with Ignited-Datatable 2.0 beta and Datatables 1.10.12 I´m using the MVC mode, I´ve seen CV mode on this.

**This is the MySQL query I try to make in Ignited style:**

```
$sql =
        "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.servicio) AS Num_Servicio_Campus,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (b.account)) AS Total_Cuentas,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(YEAR(a.periodo_fin))) AS YearFin,
        CONCAT('', FORMAT(SUM(a.consumo), 0)) AS SumatoriaConsumoEnergia,
        CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SUM(a.costo), 2)) AS SumatoriaCostoEnergia, c.campus AS Campus
        FROM `sdspanel1`.`pdc_consumo_energia` a
        INNER JOIN `sdspanel1`.`ctrl_servicios` b ON(a.servicio = b.id)
        INNER JOIN `sdspanel1`.`pdc_servicios_energia` c ON(c.cuenta = b.account)
        WHERE c.campus IS NOT NULL AND c.campus <> ''
        AND a.periodo_fin IS NOT NULL AND a.periodo_fin <> ''
        AND (YEAR(a.periodo_fin) <'1-12-31' OR YEAR(a.periodo_fin)> '2010-12-31')
        AND (YEAR(a.periodo_fin) <'2100-12-31' OR YEAR(a.periodo_fin)> '2100-12-31')";

        $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(a.periodo_fin), c.campus
            ORDER BY YEAR(a.periodo_fin) ASC, a.servicio ASC";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();

        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
```

[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y48X5.jpg)

And it works, but needs to be sorted in the Datatables way. And trying something like this [Stack Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139201/codeigniter-datatable-custom-delete-with-bootstrap-model/29139367?noredirect=1#comment46503005_29139367), but no results.

**So... this is my Ignited Datatables "try" MODEL**

```
function lista_campus()
{
    $this->load->library('datatables');
    $this->datatables->FROM('pdc_consumo_energia');
    $this->datatables->SELECT("pdc_servicios_energia.campus AS Campus,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pdc_consumo_energia.servicio) AS Num_Servicio_Campus,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(YEAR(pdc_consumo_energia.periodo_fin))) AS YearFin,
    CONCAT('', FORMAT(SUM(pdc_consumo_energia.consumo), 0)) AS SumatoriaConsumoEnergia,
    CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SUM(pdc_consumo_energia.costo), 2)) AS SumatoriaCostoEnergia,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ctrl_servicios.account)) AS Total_Cuentas", FALSE);
    $this->datatables->JOIN('ctrl_servicios', 'pdc_consumo_energia.servicio = ctrl_servicios.id', 'INNER');
    $this->datatables->JOIN('pdc_servicios_energia', 'pdc_servicios_energia.cuenta = ctrl_servicios.account', 'INNER');
    $this->datatables->WHERE('pdc_servicios_energia.campus IS NOT NULL AND pdc_consumo_energia.periodo_fin IS NOT NULL');
    $this->datatables->GROUP_BY('pdc_consumo_energia.periodo_fin', 'pdc_servicios_energia.campus');
    return $this->datatables->generate('json', '');



}
```

**Controller:**

```
function campus_buscar3()
{
    // /* Configuración de la paginación */

    $this->modelo_consumo_energia->lista_campus();
    $data['title'] = '<i class="icon-fire"></i> TEST';
    $data['subtitle'] = 'Test Vista Campus';
    $data['body'] = 'busqueda_electricidad_campus_c';
    $this->load->view('main', $data);


}
```

If I try to do the "Example" way, it can´t display a thing...

**"Finally... the View/JScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            //$(function() {
            $('#Campusini').dataTable( {


                //"order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],

                /*"aoColumnDefs": [
                    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 3 ]},
                    { 'bSearchable': true }
                ],*/
                "Processing": true,
                "ServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo site_url(); ?>consumo_electricidad/campus_buscar3',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayStart ":20,
                "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": ""
                },

                "aoColumns": [
                        { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true,  "mData": "YearFin" },
                        { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true,  "mData": "SumatoriaConsumoEnergia" },
                        { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true,  "mData": "SumatoriaCostoEnergia" },
                        { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true,  "mData": "Campus" }
                ],

                'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)

                {
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type'    : 'POST',
                        'url'     : sSource,
                        'data'    : aoData,
                        'success' : fnCallback
                    });
                }
            } );
        });
</script>




    <table id= "Campusini" class = "table table-bordered datatable table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th> Año </th>
            <th> Consumo Total </th>
            <th> Costo Total </th>
            <th> Campus </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
```

[With no results at all...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJtoB.jpg).
So any help with this mess is well received. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer all... but I saw probably the mistake:

In the controller you call the function

> $this->modelo_consumo_energia->lista_campus();

But no assigned in any variable... so no results.

I suggest to go debugging simple things and see in which part, code doesn't work, because I imagine you just wrote all this stuff and then it's impossible to know what is happening.

You are using MVC, take that! seems like Model works, now try to verify Controller and View are working too writing simple code like echo something...